# Animate div opacity on page load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery slideshow where when a thumbnail is hovered over the picture changes and a description of the picture shows up in the larger version of the picture.  All of that works fine.  I would like, however, to change the opacity of the div that contains the description of the picture (because it's overlaid on top of the larger picture).

I don't know why the below code isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#description').animate({opacity: 0.25},1000});
});

</script>
```

The selector is correct.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use `fadeTo`?

```
$('#description').fadeTo(1000, 0.25);
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/YhzPh/)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the OP's code aside from the errant `}`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#description').animate({opacity: 0.25},1000);
     //the error is in that } after the 1000 that you have

});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/QfjNb/

Comment: I've never seen that equals sign. Is it standard notation?

Comment: @Blender, yes it is. at least from what ive seen

Comment: Huh. For me, just the number works. Maybe the OP has a script error?

Comment: @Blender. i made fiddle and removed the `=`